# Error installing sql server 2012 Entreprise Edition

Tags: sql-server-2012

I m trying to install sql server 2012 entrprise (or Express ) edition in my computer but i get the this error message:

---

The operating system on this computer does not meet the minimum requirements for SQL Server 2012. For Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008 operating systems, Service pack 2 or later is required. For windows 7 or windows server 2008 R2, Service pack 1 or later is required. For more information, see Hardware and software requirements for installing SQL Server 2012 at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=195092*********
I read the requirements of microsoft but i didn't find a solution.

I have windows 7 Integral Edition &  below are my system informations,

-- processor - Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P8700 @ 2.53 GHz
-- RAM - 3 GB

-- System type - 32 bit OS

(.Net Framework 4.5 is available - PowerShell is installed  & i am using Visual studio ultimate 2012 )

Comment: At first sight i would say that the error message is clear. What is your operating system and your service pack level ?

Comment: The error message is quite clear: You don't have the proper version of Windows (or the correct Service Pack for your version). What is "Windows 7 Integral Edition"? It says you must have Service Pack 1 or later installed - do you? (Also, if you want to tell us about yourself, please use your user profile page to do so.  Questions should have technical content.)

Answer (score 3):

As per Microsoft's [requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx) page (which is linked in the error message):

SQL Server Enterprise Edition requires Windows Server 2012 R2 or Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 or Windows Server 2008 SP2. It will not install on Windows 7.

SQL Server Express Edition (which is a very different thing to Enterprise Edition) will install on Windows 7 but it requires a minimum of Windows 7 SP 1, which it seems you don't have. If so, you must install [Windows 7 service pack 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976932).