# Installing Kiln Server/Fogbugz

Tags: sql-server, fogbugz, kiln

Whilst trying to perfoem a clean install of the Kiln Server on a windows 2012 server,there are a few issues that I've come accross.
First I've had to install all the pre-requsites manually as detailed here:
http://help.fogcreek.com/8427/installing-kiln-for-your-server-without-internet-access
Our current setup requires that the sql server reside on a different machine to the one where Kiln is to be installed so when I run the installer there is a screen that asks to enter  the sql server name.
[image]
It appears that Kiln can find the instance but I get an error saying the current domain user doesn't have admin rights to make changes on the database.
I may be missing something here, but I thought to put this question up, perhaps someone else has encountered it ?

Perhaps the domain user running the kiln installer also needs to have admin rights on the sql server box as in point number 3 here:
http://help.fogcreek.com/8253/installing-kiln-for-your-server
Is there something I may be missing out ?

Comment: not really a programming question

Comment: erm , I knew it wasnt a programming question before I put it up. Is stackoverflow  specifically for 'programming questions ? I thought the reason why i tagged the question with the appropriate tags was to make it quite obvious ?  Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: and just to clarify ... help me here ... is this a programming question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507697/error-installing-sql-server-2012-entreprise-edition

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic In general mostly programming. Since I'd venture the vast majority of users here haven't setup FogBugz, you'd find better support on fogbugz forums. If you do get an error from SQL Server, type the error message EXACTLY into google, and you'll find hundreds of ways to solve your problem.

Comment: Again , Thanks for your comment. I've literally read pretty much all the fogbugz documentation on their website before I decided to post it here.Understand that this was more or less to try and see if anyone else has had the current problem that I'm having. Perhaps a better explanation would have been better than to vote down my question surely? I don't think we should assume that we know all about what issues others may have until we actually know ?Anyhow , thanks for replying back.

Comment: did you install sql server yourself manually on the other server?

Comment: As it turned out, I was able to fix the issue by adding the IIS 6 metabase compatibility feature to the windows server 2012 machine.The fogbugz installer  needed this feature in order to proceed with the installation.This is one of those things that may not be obvious if indeed this is a first time install.Although the installer was able to connect to the database, it couldn't proceed with the IIS configuration steps which is why I kept getting an error.

Comment: hey, that would have been my second guess! :)

Comment: If you found your answer, please add it below and accept it as a "self-answer" to help out fellow folks!